# Using Two values returned from Sub queries to calculate Sum, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

After a couple of hours of trying this myself I've reached a point where I figured I'd put this question out on the site. In principal I feel what I'm trying to do isn't overly difficult, I think I have a knowledge gap somewhere so that may be playing a part in things.

Ultimately I am trying to display one row of information on a screen and have two sub queries using the SUM function in Oracle, these two are both working. One returns a number value relating to labor, and the other returns a number value relating to parts needed. Next I am trying to sum both of these returned to SELECT a column which I'm calling grand_total. However, I keep getting ORA-00904 error, Invalid Identifier. Am I alaising wrong? Is my alias in the wrong spot? Is what I'm trying to do possible? Below is my code:

```
 cars.body,
 cars.payment,
   (
     select sum(parts) from (select distinct(item_number) from account where  
      refnumber='123456')
    ) P,
    (
      select sum(labor) from (select distinct(item_number) from account where acct_id='123456')
      )  L,
     (
       sum(L + P)
     ) as grand_total,
```

Comment: Is this the full SQL statement?

Comment: If you provide some sample data and explain what you need, we may be able to assist you in providing better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement isn't complete, and your data model makes no sense to me.  However, the immediate problem is that you are:

1. Trying to select columns from a sub query that aren't in that sub query. `select distinct(item_number) from account where refnumber='123456'` has no selectable columns.  There is no column named `parts` or `labor` in the select clause of that query.
2. You are trying to reference a column alias in the same select clause.  The select clause items all execute in parallel, so there is no way to reference the alias `L` elsewhere in the same select clause.  You need to nest, I recommend a Common Table Expression.

Hypothetically, if your schema was

```
create table account
(acct_id int 
,item_number int
,refnumber int);

create table cars
(car_id int
,body varchar2(100)
,payment number
,parts number
,labor number);
```

Then the following would be valid SQL:

```
WITH subtotals AS (
 SELECT cars.body,
  cars.payment,
  sum(parts) parts_total,
  sum(labor) labor_total
 FROM cars
 INNER JOIN account ON cars.car_id = account.refnumber
 GROUP BY cars.body, 
  cars.payment
)
SELECT body,
  payment,
  parts_total,
  labor_total,
  parts_total + labor_total as grand_total
FROM subtotals;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line make no sense, you can't have two from in one select statement.

```
 select sum(parts) from (select distinct(item_number) from account
```

Perhaps try below? You can sum it in one query since both from same table **account**

```
select distinct itemnumber,
      sum(parts) over(partition by itemnumber) + sum(labour) over(partition by itemnumber) as grandtotal
  from (
        -- this is dummy data just for make the select statement work
        select 'itemone' itemnumber, 16 parts, 13 labour
          from dual
        union all
        select 'itemone' itemnumber, 32 parts, 93 labour
          from dual
        union all
        select 'itemtwo' itemnumber, 12 parts, 17 labour
          from dual
        union all
        select 'itemthree' itemnumber, 24 parts, 43 labour
          from dual
        union all
        select 'itemthree' itemnumber, 25 parts, 52 labour
          from dual
        union all
        select 'itemfour' itemnumber, 112 parts, 73 labour
          from dual)
```